# Selecting and alter 3rd value based on multiple other columns' values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and two variables.

I have variables, `"ArrivalDate"` and `"ModelingUnitID."`

The dataframe  has 7+ columns including `'ArrivalDate'`, `'ModelingUnitID'`, `'CurrentAllocation'`

I want to retrieve the value of `'CurrentAllocation'` from the data frame by using the values in data frame A and set a variable (x) to this value, then add the value of 1 and replace the original value.

Unable to retrieve a value that I'm not filtering on.

Thanks for the help!

```py
X = df['CurrentAllocation'][(df['ArrivalDate']==ArrivalDate)&(df['ModelingUnitID']==ModelingUnitID)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rearranging the order?

```
X = df[(df['ArrivalDate']==ArrivalDate)&(df['ModelingUnitID']==ModelingUnitID)]['CurrentAllocation']
```

So first, you would filter your entire dataframe, then select the single 'CurrentAllocation' column.

Comment: When I perform this command, I retrieve more than just the value, but instead a long string "26    3.0 Name: StaffingStandardsValue, dtype: float64" Is there a way to return just the value "3.0" so I can later add this value to other numbers.

Comment: I would think that X is a pandas Series from this command, try adding a .to_frame() and see what happens.